Module of finite length is a submodule of an Artinian ring

Let $(R,m)$ be a Cohen-Macaulay local ring and $\dim R=n$. Let $M$ be a finitey generated $R$- module of finite length and finite projective dimension. Then we have an exact sequence $0\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow (R/(x_1,...,x_n))^m\longrightarrow Q\longrightarrow0$, where $(x_1,...,x_n)$ is an $R$-sequence.

I was thinking about Matlis duality. Let $M^\vee=$Hom$_R(M,E_R(R/m))$. We are able to find an $R$-sequence $(x_1,...,x_n)$ such that $(R/(x_1,...,x_n))^m\twoheadrightarrow M^\vee \rightarrow0$ is an exact sequence. By Matlis duality, we have an inclusion $M\cong M^{\vee\vee}\hookrightarrow ((R/(x_1,...,x_n))^m)^\vee$. It remains to show $(R/(x_1,...,x_n))^\vee\cong R/(x_1,...,x_n)$.
However, we have Hom$_R(R/(x_1,...,x_n),E_R(R/m))\cong E_{R/(x_1,..,x_n)}(R/m)$. I don't think in general one has $E_{R/(x_1,..,x_n)}(R/m)\cong R/(x_1,...,x_n)$. Does $(R/(x_1,...,x_n))^m\twoheadrightarrow M^\vee$ with the assumption that $M$ has finite projective dimension imply the $R/(x_1,...,x_n)$ also has finite injective dimension?
How can I get the desired result?

As you have said, let $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n$ be a regular sequence contained in the annihilator of $M$. Using the Koszul complex associated to the $x_i$s check that $\operatorname{Tor}^n(R/(x_1,\ldots,x_n), M)=M$. Let $0\to F_n\to\cdots\to F_0\to M\to 0$ be a free resolution of $M$. Tensoring by $R/(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ one gets $M=\operatorname{Tor}^n(R/(x_1,\ldots,x_n), M)\subset F_n\otimes R/(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ proving what you want.
